# Hash anchor hides content on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, anchor

I have two divs side by side. I have used [this](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/equalheight) trick to make them same height.

Now, I have a problem with anchor links. If you click on anchor link it will hide content that is above that section.

Have a look at jsfiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/bLtjj/

Is there any solution for this one? jQuery or CSS.

Comment: That's how linking to an anchor works.  What behavior were you expecting/wanting?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have overflow set to hidden in the wrapper class.

Try this

```
.wrapper { overflow:visible; }
```

See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLtjj/1/)

Comment: Yeah, but note that you are unable to scroll back to the top, the text in the main content before section is hidden (more like slipped from the screen). jQuery solution to prevent using wrong offset would do the thing.

Comment: OK, I see that now, sorry did not notice it. It is because you are setting the overflow property to hidden. See my updated answer

Comment: Setting overflow to visible will actually reveal huge gap in the divs - at the bottom. So not. It's not the solution. Here's how it works (properly) when using fixed height values (ignore gap on the bottom - that's not good). http://jsfiddle.net/GFNTD/

Answer (score 0):

really confusing question.
with anchor you will to link position.
all the texts/contents above it will be at top, they r not hidden.
as Surreal Dreams told, anchor work like this.

what are you expecting there?

Comment: Have you saw this example : http://jsfiddle.net/bLtjj/ notice how text in the main content is cut off once you click the anchor. you can't go back. And the huge padding reveals at the bottom.